# Bash concatenate line from file w/ boolean

Tags: bash

I've been trying to read in a file line by line and output each line with the value and boolean result.

**Contents of the text file**

```
082843ab-c1e5-4729-8c03-2cec11996f01
09180b12-21b3-4bdb-a27b-ef9c026909f3
```

**Script used to parse the file**

```
#!/bin/bash

my_file="${1}"

declare -a myarray
let i=0
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line_data; do
    myarray[i]="${line_data}"
    ((++i))
done < $my_file

force_transmission="true"
let i=0
while (( ${#myarray[@]} > i ));do
    new_var=${myarray[i++]}
    combined_var="$new_var $force_transmission"
    echo $combined_var

    #this will print out the external id(file)
    #printf "${myarray[i++]}\n"
done
```

**Expectataion**

```
082843ab-c1e5-4729-8c03-2cec11996f01 true
09180b12-21b3-4bdb-a27b-ef9c026909f3 true
```

**Actual**

```
true3ab-c1e5-4729-8c03-2cec11996f01
trueb12-21b3-4bdb-a27b-ef9c026909f3
```

Any help would be very much appreciated, i've tried like 5 variations of this

Comment: It is working fine as expected!

Comment: I just tried your script on ubuntu for windows and it outputs as expected. I don't get your actual.

Comment: How are you calling your script?

Comment: ./my_script.sh myfile.txt

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem is obvious -- the input file has DOS newlines.

Comment: That said, your code is an *extremely* verbose way to write `while read -r line; do echo "$line true"; done` -- or, to fix the bug; `echo "${line%$'\r'} true"`. Also consider running through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: BTW, this is literally the **very first thing** in the *Before asking about problematic code* section of the [`bash` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file has DOS newlines. When printed, these send the cursor back to the beginning of the line, thus overwriting content afterwards.

Use `dos2unix` on your input file, or modify the line:

```
new_var=${new_var%$'\r'} # remove $'\r', a CR character, from the end of new_var
```

Comment: That did it, thank you.  This helps me from not having to manually parse file before running the script.

Comment: I'd give you an upvote but I dont have enough rep, will have to circle back when I do. cheer.

Answer (score 0):

If that's what you want to do use one of the specialized tools instead of `bash` scripting

**UPDATED** 
to eliminate the `CR`, just

```
$ sed 's/\r$/ true/' file

082843ab-c1e5-4729-8c03-2cec11996f01 true
09180b12-21b3-4bdb-a27b-ef9c026909f3 true
```

Comment: Either of these will have the exact same behavior as the OP's original code if given an input file with CRLFs.

Comment: This did have the same result but also made me realize that my file was part of the problem.  thank you.